# How to get multiple rows values in single row using dict and list

Tags: python, django

I have a django model ReportDashboard, that have multiple row for same report based on date and time. I want put in single result which have report Name as Key of dictionary and values are list of all updated_on from other rows.

```
"""Required OUTPUT"""
{'Daily Pickup':[2016-04-19 11:48:00,2016-04-18 11:40:00, 2016-04-17 10:30:00]} 
{'Surface MIS LHRTO':[2016-04-19 11:52:00, DATE2,DATE3,DATE4,DATE5, SO ON]}
{...........}
{...........}
```

**Django Model**

```
repo=ReportDashboard.objects.filter(status=2)
for r in repo:
    print r.report_name, r.updated_on
```

**Output**

```
Daily Pickup 2016-04-19 11:48:00
Surface MIS LHRTO 2016-04-19 11:52:00
Daily Pickup 2016-04-18 11:40:00
Daily Pickup 2016-04-17 10:30:00
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest done in python ([groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is handy here as pointed out by @Anentropic):

```
from itertools import groupby

repos = [(r.report_name, r.updated_on) for r in repo]
repos.sort()  # sorts by name and date

# group by name and collect dates, use as key/value in dict-comprehension
result = {k: [r[1] for r in g] for k, g in groupby(repos, lambda x: x[0])}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping